# Grep template for extracting lines where second word has only two vowels

Tags: grep, regular-expression

For example, i have file with content

```
hello world
it's nice to see you
amazing night
what a wonderful day
my name is Robert
still breathing
speaking bottom soul
something wrong
```

I need to match those lines, in which second word has exactly two vowels.
So the output should be:

```
it's nice to see you
my name is Robert
speaking bottom soul
```

How can I do this using grep?

Comment: @thrig, i don't have much experience in working with regular expressions, so the last thing i tried `grep -e ".*\s[aueioy]\{2\}" test.txt`. BTW, it's still wrong.

Comment: Does it have to be grep? it would be simpler and clearer IMHO using a tool such as awk or perl that handles whitespace delimited fields more naturally. For example in awk you could use the return value of a `gsub` on `$2` (or in perl use the return value of a `tr` on `$F[1]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

grep with extended regular expressions:

```
grep -iE '^[^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+([^aeiou]*[aeiou]){2}[^aeiou]*\>' file
```

grep with pcre

```
grep -iP '^\S+\s+([^aeiou]*[aeiou]){2}[^aeiou]*\b' file
```

perl (honestly, I did this independent of steeldriver's comment)

```
perl -ane 'print if (lc($F[1]) =~ tr/aeiou/aeiou/) == 2' file
```

awk

```
awk '{col2 = tolower($2); gsub(/[aeiou]/,"",col2)} length($2) - length(col2) == 2' file
```